# Order of Constructor Call for super() in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I am trying to reason why this code isn't returning what I expect:

```
public class Bike {
    int height;
    int color;
    public Bike(int height, int color) {
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

public class MountainBike extends Bike {
    public MountainBike(int height, int color) {
        super(height, color);
        super.height = 200;
        System.out.println(super.height);
        System.out.println(height);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MountainBike a = new MountainBike(1, 1);

    }
}
```

which returns

```
200
1
```

I expected `System.out.println(height)` to print out `200` but instead only the super call does.

The order of operations would be:

**0.** `all fields including superclass fields are declared and memory is allocated`

**1.** `super() call from MountainBike constructor is called`

**2.** `super() call from Bike constructor is called`

**3.** `Object super() call is called`

**4.** `Bike fields are initialized (nothing happens in this case)`

**5.** `Bike constructor is executed (height and color are set to arguments from the super() call from MountainBike)`

**6.** `MountainBike fields are initialized (nothing happens in this case)`

**7.** `MountainBike constructor is executed (should set super.height to 200 and then both System.out.println calls should return 200)`

Can someone point my error in this case?

Comment: I have a task for you: check what shadowing is and how one can avoid it (or work with it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.out.println(height);` in the `MountainBike` constructor is printing the value of the argument passed to the constructor, which is 1. Faced with multiple variables with the same name, Java will use the "closest" in scope first.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing has nothing to do with the order of constructors.

You are "hiding" the field hight by a parameter.
Now your are updating the field and only the field.

The you print the field and afterwards the parameter which still is the original value passed to the constructor.

By the way: First the constructor of Bike is executed.

Comment: Why would Bike constructor be called first? In this case it gets executed but not called first I thought.

Comment: Yes, executed is the right word. I changed it. Calling order: Mountainbike -> Bike. Execution order: Bike -> Mountainbike